# Check if PayPal API/Service is available/up

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am integrating PayPal into a Java payment service and was wondering if there is easy way to tell if PayPal API is up and running. I checked the documentation and found the error code `10101 - This API Temporarily Unavailable`  but couldn't find a method that should be used to poll the service. The idea is if the API is down I won't show PayPal as available payment option. The actual integration is Express checkout.

Answer (score 0):

It's very, very rare that Paypal live APIs go down (in 2009 PayPal was doing $3,000 per second in transactions so a downtime costs them LOTS of money). I don't know that I would make an API call just to see if it's down. Just handle the errors when they happen.